How to use calculated width for SVG rect?
I was trying to develop a svg skeleton image for showing it while data is loading, here is code which I was using for editing svg.


// converting svg tag to data url and setting it as background image
const svgURL = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,' + btoa(document.querySelector('svg').outerHTML);
document.querySelector('#xyz').style.backgroundImage = `url(${svgURL})`;
svg {
  height: 48px;
}
.xyz {
  background-repeat: repeat-y !important;
  background-size: 100% 48px !important;
}
<svg
  width="100%"
  height="48"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  stroke="none"
  fill="grey"
>
  <circle cx="24" cy="24" r="12" />
  <rect height="20" width="calc(100% - 60px)" x="48" y="14" rx="10" ry="7" fill="grey" />
</svg>

<div id="xyz" style="border: red 1px solid; height: 300px; width: 100%"></div>



As you can see same svg is rendered correctly if it is part of html, but as soon as we use it as background, width of rectangle is not setting correctly.
Any idea what I am doing wrong and how we can fix it?

Seem fine on Firefox. Report any bugs to the appropriate browser bugtracker

CSS calc() can still be unpredictable across different browsers when applied to SVG elements.
You may use this hack using <line> elements instead of <rect>.
We're defining a length via x2=100%,
apply a translateX transformation to shorten the line to the right
and a left x offset.
Tested in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.


// converting svg tag to data url and setting it as background image
const svgURL = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,' + btoa(document.querySelector('svg').outerHTML);
document.querySelector('#xyz').style.backgroundImage = `url(${svgURL})`;
svg {
  height: 48px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.xyz {
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 100% 48px !important;
  resize:both;
  overflow:auto;
  
}
<svg
  width="100%"
  height="48"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  stroke="none"
  fill="grey"
>
  <circle cx="24" cy="24" r="12" />
  <line x1="110" y1="24" x2="100%" y2="24" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="grey" style="transform:translate(-40px, 0)"></line>
</svg>

<h3>Resize me</h3>
<div class="xyz" id="xyz" style="border: red 1px solid; height: 300px; width: 100%"></div>




Your main issue was a missing viewBox and not removing the whitespace between SVG tags.
IMG.src is more forgiving on whitespace
FYI; The xmlns NameSpace is required for backgroundImage and IMG, but can be ommitted when used as inline SVG in a (modern) HTML document.
You don't need the oldskool Base64 in modern Browsers, just escape some special URI characters
(I took the oldskool global ID shortcut for brevity, use proper references in your production code)


function escape(svg) {
  return "data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8," + svg
    .replace(/\>[\t\s\n ]+\</g, "><") // replace all whitespace BETWEEN tags  
    .replace(/#/g, '%23')
    .replace(/"/g, "'")
    .replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
}

XYZ.style.backgroundImage = `url("${escape(SVG.outerHTML)}")`;  
IMG.src = escape(SVG.outerHTML);
img, svg { width: 100%;  height: 40px;  background: pink }
#XYZ {
  border: red 1px solid; height: 60px; width: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 100% 40px;
}
<b>Original SVG</b>
<svg id=SVG xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 350 50">
  <circle cx="24" cy="24" r="12" fill="green"/>
  <rect height="20" width="calc(100% - 40px)" x="48" y="14" rx="10" ry="7" fill="teal" />
</svg>

<b>backgroundImage</b>
<div id="XYZ"></div>

<b>IMG</b>
<img id=IMG>



